# How to Change Android Studio Layout Editor Background Color

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm building a custom view and it's nice to see it coming together in the Layout Editor, but the problem is that the background is white, so any white elements in my view are effectively hidden. Is there any way to change the background that it uses? My view doesn't have a background itself, it's just paths drawn on a Canvas.

[image]

Comment: please try the answer I provided to just change the Layout editor background, and let me know if you still face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

To change the background of the editor goto **File, Settings, Editor, Colors & Fonts and select General**. You'll see an item called **"Default text"**. On the right of the window you will see a checkbox for background. Click in the color window and choose whichever color you prefer. Now the entire editor window will show that color as the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background of your Layout by changing the theme of your Layout editor.

See I also had a white background for my Layout editor like you and then changed it to a dark one.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks like what I need, but that toolbar isn't present in my layout editor. It is when I'm editing a layout xml file, but not when I'm working on my custom view code.